# coarse moduli space and $\pi_0$

Tags: algebraic-stacks, ag.algebraic-geometry

I've been reading this really nice paper by Alper http://math.columbia.edu/~jarod/good_moduli_spaces.pdf, and there's a question that doesn't seem to be answered (perhaps it's not relevant).

Any stack F has a corresponding `sheaf of connected components' (or sheaf of isomorphism classes), by taking $\pi_0^{pr}(F)(S) = \pi_0 (F(S))$ and then sheafifying. (where $\pi_0$ of a groupoid, or more generally a category, is the set of isomorphism classes)

If $X$ is an Artin stack (although I'm currently more interested in DM stacks) and $X$ admits a good moduli space, then is $X \to \pi_0(X)$ a good moduli space?

Also, when is the good moduli space a scheme (and not just an algebraic space)?

And finally, if $X$ = $Spec R$ is affine and $G$ acts on it (I'm mainly interested in the $G$ finite case), is $\pi_0([X/G]) = Spec R^G$?

Comment: Why do you expect there to be any kind of relation between moduli spaces and connected components ? If `$X$` is a connected scheme over a field `$k$`, then I guess that `$X$` is a good moduli space of itself while `$\pi_0(X)$` is something like `$Spec(k)$`.

Comment: apologies for the confusing notation: if X is a sheaf on th, say, etale site of affine schemes. Then X(R) is a set for all rings R. Understand this set as a discrete topological space, therefore it makes sense to take the connected components of it. This gives me back the same set!(as you wrote: a scheme is a good moduli space of itself). If X is a stack of groupoids, then X(R) is a groupoid which (by taking nerves) can be interpreted as a (1-connected) topological space: it makes sense to consider $\pi_1$ (automorphisms), $\pi_0$ (connected components), so $\pi_0(X)$ is the shf closest to X.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP means pi_0 in the groupoid sense, so that pi_0 of a scheme is itself.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: @david roberts: sice you popped by, isn't $\pi_0$ left adjoint to the inclusion of sheaves in stacks? So $\pi_0(X)$ is universal among maps towards sheaves. Assume now 'having a good moduli space' means to have a morphism $X \to Y$, with $Y$ an algebraic space which (among perhaps other things) is universal towards maps to algebraic spaces. Can't we deduce from this that $Y = \pi_0(X)$? This sounds too easy: should I turn off the computer and take a nap?

Comment: @YS - "left adjoint to the inclusion of sheaves in stacks?" I believe so. I'll address your other question in a little bit.

Comment: I think the question is yes, but I'll check properly before I answer.

Comment: I've heard people say that $\pi_0$ is badly behaved in general. But if there's something that should approximate a stack with a sheaf it's $\pi_0$!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have probably already come up with the answer yourself, but I just thought the question shouldn't
hang around unanswered in the forum.

What you call "the sheaf of connected components", I would call the *coarse sheaf* of the stack or the 
*sheaf associated to the stack*. It is usually not representable by an algebraic space. When it is,
the stack is called a *gerbe* and the map to the coarse sheaf is called the *structure morphism* of the gerbe.

A gerbe with structure morphism $X \to Y$ is fppf locally on $Y$ of the form $B_YG := [Y/G]$, where $G$ is
a group-algebraic space which is fppf over $Y$, and the action on $Y$ is trivial.
(In fact, it is even étale locally on this form, since the structure morphism $X \to Y$ of a gerbe is smooth.)

Although gerbes certainly have at lot of good properties, the structure morphisms of a gerbe need not be a
good moduli space in the sense of Alper. It is, exactly when $G$ above is linearly reductive.

The property of being a gerbe as a very strong property. Thus good (or a coarse) moduli spaces
are seldom coarse sheaves. In particular $Spec\ R^G$ will usually not be the coarse sheaf of $[Spec\ R / G]$.
Taking the stack quotient and then taking the associated sheaf, is the same as taking the sheaf quotient
directly. The result is seldom (never?) representable unless the action of $G/N$ is free, where $N$ is the kernel
of the action.