# What are the most attractive Turing undecidable problems in mathematics?

Tags: computability-theory, big-list, examples, lo.logic

What are the most attractive [Turing undecidable problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) in mathematics?

There are *thousands* of examples, so please post here only the most attractive, best examples. Some examples already appear on the Wikipedia page.

Standard community wiki rules. One example per post please. I will accept the answer I find to be the most attractive, according to the following criteria:

- Examples must be undecidable in the sense of Turing computability. (Please not that this is not the same as the sense of logical independence; think of [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups), not Continuum Hypothesis.)
- The best examples will arise from natural mathematical questions.
- The best examples will be easy to describe, and understandable by most or all mathematicians.
- (Challenge) The *very* best examples, if any, will in addition have intermediate Turing degree, strictly below the halting problem. That is, they will be undecidable, but not because the halting problem reduces to them.

Edit: This question is a version of a previous question by [Qiaochu Yuan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/290/qiaochu-yuan), inquiring which problems in mathematics are able to simulate Turing machines, with the example of the [MRDP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_tenth_problem) on diophantine equations, as well as the simulation of Turing machines via PDEs. He has now graciously merged his question here.

Comment: I guess Qiaochu's question dissapeared in the process of being merged? Can someone post the link regarding PDE's that was on his question?

Comment: Somewhat related: [A simple decision problem whose decidability is not known](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/18846) and [Decision problems for which it is unknown whether they are decidable](https://mathoverflow.net/q/345388).

Answer (score 135):

The mortality problem for $3\times 3$ matrices: given a finite set $F$ of $3\times 3$
integer matrices, decide whether the zero matrix is a product of members of $F$ 
(with repetitions allowed). This was proved unsolvable by Michael Paterson, 
Studies in Applied Mathematics 49 (1970), 105--107, doi: [10.1002/sapm1970491105](https://doi.org/10.1002/sapm1970491105).

The corresponding problem for $2\times 2$ matrices is apparently still open.

**Edit** (11 September 2016): The problem for $2\times 2$ matrices is apparently *still* open, despite the solution of a seemingly similar problem mentioned in Igor Potapov's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/249542) below.

Comment: ... or just two $21 \times 21$ matrices

Comment: Interesting ... I hadn't heard that result. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Halava, V.; Harju, T.; Hirvensalo, M. (2007). "Undecidability Bounds for Integer Matrices Using Claus Instances". International Journal of Foundations of Computer Science 18 (5): 931–948. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.154.9129&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Note the recent preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6700 which improves these results. Undecidability now holds for five 3*3 matrices or two 15*15 matrices.

Comment: Similar to tiles in PCP

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think Igor's answer nor the paper linked deal with mortality problem, but rather with the identity problem (i.e. we ask whether identity matrix, not zero matrix, can be expressed using these matrices).

Comment: @Wojowu The first problem in the paper is the *membership problem*, which has the mortality problem as the special case $M=$ zero matrix. So by solving the membership problem they also solve the mortality problem for $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Unless the paper proves something more general than is stated in the abstract (which I don't think it does, by skimming through the paper), then the result doesn't establish general membership problem, but rather the membership problem for _nonsingular matrices_. Mortality problem is trivial if we restrict to sets of matrices generated by nonsingular matrices, since we can't express zero matrix as a product of nonsingular matrices.

Comment: @Wojowu Oops, sorry -- I failed to notice the nonsingular condition.

Answer (score 70):

As I mentioned in the other thread, [Matiyasevich's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich.27s_theorem) implies that it is undecidable whether a system of Diophantine equations over $\mathbb{Z}$ has a solution (Hilbert's 10th Problem).  I have to mention some related results here: if $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ then the problem is still not decidable, if replaced by $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C},$ or [$\mathbb{Q}_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) then the problem is decidable, and if replaced by $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ the answer is not known!  ([Reference](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/aws2003.pdf).)  I believe it is not even known whether the answer is yes for some number fields but no for others (which would be truly bizarre).

Comment: Thanks very much, Qiaochu, for moving your question over here. I appreciate it, and I think we'll get a good list.

Comment: I find these results really interesting; in a way it shows why analysis is so successful.

Comment: What's $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ and $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$? :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 It would be more courteous to ask what ${\mathbb Q}_p$ is before editing Qiaochu's answer. MathOverflow is intended for professional mathematicians and people write their answers with that audience is mind; and we do not quite follow the usual StackExchange norms when it comes to rewriting other people's content

Comment: @YemonChoi feel free to revert, you our Qiaochu if you feel its better. This question is very basic however, and possibly should not have been asked here on this site, but it is too late now. It will also be Googled by many compsci undergrads who might now know what those sets are.

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 "This question is very basic however, and possibly should not have been asked here on this site" I strongly disagree. I think this question is fine for MO. Separately, I've edited the answer - I hesitate to undo your edit unilaterally, but I think it's more gracefully done by not adding a parenthetical.

Comment: @NoahSchweber that's OK, thanks. What's []  and (())? :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series) respectively.

Answer (score 69):

I'm surprised nobody's mentioned the [Post correspondence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem).  Like the tiling problem, it seems like something so basic, there has to be some simple way to brute-force it... but no.

Comment: I second this problem, which is the gateway to many other unsolvability proofs, such as the one for the mortality problem for $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: Note that http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6700 (mentioned in comments to another answer) also proves PCP undecidable even when restricted to only *four pairs of binary words*.

Answer (score 53):

There is no algorithm that given positive integers $K$ and $x$ can decide if the following concrete Diophantine equation has a solution over positive integers:
\begin{align}
&(elg^2 + \alpha - (b-xy)q^2)^2 + (q - b^{5^{60}})^2 + (\lambda + q^4 - 1 - \lambda b^5)^2 + \\
&(\theta + 2z - b^5)^2 + (u + t \theta - l)^2 + (y + m \theta - e)^2 + (n - q^{16})^2 + \\
&((g + eq^3 + lq^5 + (2(e - z \lambda)(1 + xb^5 + g)^4 + \lambda b^5 + \lambda b^5 q^4)q^4)(n^2 - n) + \\
&(q^3 - bl + l + \theta \lambda q^3 + (b^5-2)q^5)(n^2 - 1) - r)^2 + \\
&(p - 2w s^2 r^2 n^2)^2 + (p^2 k^2 - k^2 + 1 - \tau^2)^2 + \\
&(4(c - ksn^2)^2 + \eta - k^2)^2 + (r + 1 + hp - h - k)^2 + \\
&(a - (wn^2 + 1)rsn^2)^2 + (2r + 1 + \phi - c)^2 + \\
&(bw + ca - 2c + 4\alpha \gamma - 5\gamma - d)^2 + \\
&((a^2 - 1)c^2 + 1 - d^2)^2 + ((a^2 - 1)i^2c^4 + 1 - f^2)^2 + \\
&(((a + f^2(d^2 - a))^2 - 1) (2r + 1 + jc)^2 + 1 - (d + of)^2)^2 + \\
&(((zuy)^2+u)^2 + y-K)^2 = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: This sort of thing always shocks me. 


Comment: What is a source for this? Does this equation mean or represent anything?

Comment: This Diophantine equation can encode any r.e. set. It is derived from "Undecidable diophantine equations" by James P. Jones, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) Volume 3, Number 2 (1980), 859-862. http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1980-03-02/S0273-0979-1980-14832-6/S0273-0979-1980-14832-6.pdf

Comment: It is clear that there is a Diophantine equation of power 4 with the same property (just add enough auxiliary variables and clauses of the form $(v_1 - v_2 v_3)^2$), but it is unknown if there is one of power 3.

Comment: The equation is quite simple, except for that $5^{60}$ exponent...

Comment: Грехи наши тяжкие... :D

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Is there a particular $K$ I can choose (e.g. $K=10$) such that the solvability of the equations is undecidable? Or is it just that there's theoretically some $K$ for which it's undecidable, but we can't really pin down which $K$?

Comment: @chausies For every concrete $K$, the equation either has solutions, or it doesn't. So, either a program that simply prints “Yes”, or a program that simply prints “No” will give a correct answer. If you want to know which of the programs is correct, and you want to be able to do it for every $K$, we are back to the original problem. There is no universal algorithm that can decide it.

Comment: The answer above contains several errors. For instance, it states that the algorithm takes only a positive integer $K$ as input, when in fact it takes two positive integers: $K$ and $x$. Moreover, the third sub-term of the equation's first term should be $-(b - xy)q^2$ instead of $-bq^2$. Additionally, Jones specified that the "unknowns ... range over *positive* integers" [emphasis added], while the answer mentions only "solution[s] over non-negative integers." 

For a correct version of the equation, see https://www.takingthefun.com/2023/03/an-undecidable-diophantine-equation.html.

Comment: @jordancurve Thank you for your comment. Please feel free to correct the answer.

Answer (score 51):

The [Word Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) for groups is undecidable. This is the problem, given a finite group presentation and a word, to decide if that word is the group identity in that presentation. The problem is undecidable because one may encode the Halting problem for Turing machines. Basically, for each Turing machine program, one can construct a group presentation and a word, such that the program halts if and only if that word is the identity.

Comment: Closely related is that computing $H^2$ of a finitely-presented group is impossible: Gordon, C. Some embedding theorems and undecidability questions for groups. Combinatorial and geometric group theory (Edinburgh, 1993), 105--110, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 204, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1995.

Comment: There are numerous closely related problems. The conjugacy problem, for example, is the problem of deciding whether two words are conjugate in a given presentation. Also: deciding the order of a group element or deciding whether the order exceeds a given number. 

Comment: I thought the conjugacy problem was a special case of the word problem? (since $zxz^{-1}=y$ iff $zxz^{-1}y^{-1}=e$.) Or is it undecidable in some kind of independent way?

Comment: Tom, you are just given two words x and y, but not z. You could try out various z, but there isn't time to try them all. But the converse reduction is true: the word problem reduces to the conjugacy problem, since w=e if and only if w is conjugate to e. 

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. That conjugacy problem is rather less trivial than the one I had in mind...

Comment: In a way, conjugacy problem also reduces to the word problem: to test whether x and y are conjugate in G, impose the relation x=1 and determine whether y=1 in the quotient.

Comment: The "reduction" of the conjugacy problem to the word problem is not always computable, since there are groups with unsolvable conjugacy
problem but solvable word problem. See C.F. Miller, III, *On group-theoretic decision problems and their classification*, Annals of Math. Studies 68  (1971).

Comment: John, Victor's argument is computably reducing the conjugacy problem for one presentation to the word problem of another presentation. 

Comment: Joel, I take your point. I was thinking that a solvable word problem 
would remain solvable when a relation $x=1$ is added, but on second
thoughts this is not clear. Nonetheless, I'm still dubious about
Victor's proposed reduction. If $y=1$ in "$G$ plus $x=1$" it could be, e.g., that $y=zx^{2}z^{-1}$ in $G$, so $y$ is conjugate to $x^2$ but not necessarily to $x$.

Comment: John, yes, I think you are right. In general, however, the conjugacy problem for arbitrary presentations (and not just one fixed presentation) does reduce to the word problem for arbitrary presentations, since both are equivalent to the halting problem. That is, the halting problem famously reduces to the word problem, which reduces to the conjugacy problem as I explained, but this clearly reduces to the halting problem since it is $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: And about your other remark: the free group has a solvable word problem, but all finitely presented groups are obtained by adding finitely many relations to it. So it must be that sometimes a solvable word problem is made unsolvable this way.

Comment: Well, yes, the conjugacy problem does reduce to the word problem via
the halting problem, but I'm not excited about this reduction. On the
other hand, I love your argument that adding one relation can change a
word problem from solvable to unsolvable. So much easier than trying
to find an example! 

Comment: It is probebely worth mentioning that even whetehr a finitely presented group is trivial is undecideble.

Answer (score 47):

The [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), the mother of them all.

Comment: Is there an undecidable problem that is actually *weaker* than the halting problem? Most of the problems stated here can be solved using a halting problem oracle, but also the halting problem can be solved using an oracle for them. Is there an undecidable problem X that can be solved using a halting problem oracle, but the halting problem cannot be solved with an X-oracle?

Comment: @Christoph-SimonSenjak  Yes, there are such intermediate problems, strictly between the decidable sets and the halting problem. There is a c.e. problem that is not decidable, but which is not Turing-equivalent to the halting problem. This is the solution of Post's problem, solved by Friedburg-Muchnik. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_problem#Post.27s_problem_and_the_priority_method.

Comment: @Christoph-SimonSenjak http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec4.html

Comment: @Christoph-SimonSenjak https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26340/are-there-any-existing-problems-that-wouldnt-be-solvable-with-a-halting-oracle

Answer (score 46):

[Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem) says that it is undecidable to tell whether an expression $E$ satisfies $E=0$, where $E$ is generated by $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\pi,\ln 2,x\}$ and the composition of operations in $\{+,-,\times,\sin,\exp, \mathrm{abs}\}$.

(I thought this deserves its own answer, even if it's given as a comment on [this other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11540/what-are-the-most-attractive-turing-undecidable-problems-in-mathematics/11555#11555).)

Comment: Is the problem known to become decidable if $\operatorname{abs}$ is removed from the allowed operations?

Comment: @DavidZhang yes, combining some later results (see http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/321574.321591 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/321850.321856), we can remove the dependence on $\ln 2$, $\mathrm{abs}$ and $\exp$.

Comment: Is this true?! It sounds wrong.

Comment: @didest Could you elaborate on your comment? The second paper you cite refers to the undecidability of  $\exists x\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $E(x)=0$, while Richardsons's theorem is about $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $E(x)=0$.

Answer (score 45):

The [Tiling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile) is undecidable. This is the problem, given a finite set of tile types, to determine whether there is an arrangement of them with adjacent sides matching that tiles the plane. The problem is undecidable because the Halting problem for Turing machines reduces to it, in the sense that every Turing machine program corresponds to a tiling problem, which has a tiling if and only if the program fails to halt. Basically, the run of the machine is encoded into the tiling, which can continue as long as the program keeps running.

Comment: Moreover, the tiling extension problem is undecidable: can a tiling of a part of the plane be extended to the whole plane? There are some interesting examples of partial Penrose tilings with many pieces which are non-extendable in a non-obvious way.

Comment: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dharel/SCANNED.PAPERS/RucurringDominoes.pdf

Comment: This has a consequence of interest to 3-manifold topologists, concerning branched surfaces --- a branched surface is a compact 2-complex such that at each point $x$ there is a well-defined "tangent plane", and there exists a smoothly embedded open disc containing $x$. Ramin Naimi (unpublished) proved that if a branched surface is embeddable in a 3-manifold then it is decidable whether every 2-cell is in the image of a complete immersion of $R^2$. However, for abstract branched surfaces, this is undecidable, because every tiling problem can be encoded as an abstract branched surface.

Answer (score 38):

Let $n\geq 3$. Given two embeddings of $S^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$, the problem of determining whether they are equivalent (via a deformation of $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$) is undecidable (the case $n=2$ is open; for $n=1$ an algorithm exists).

By the way, Bjorn Poonen has a wonderful talk on this topic, titled [Undecidability Everywhere](http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/slides/cantrell3.pdf).

Comment: What kind of deformation of $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$?

Comment: An ambient isotopy

Comment: It's still undecidable up to an ambient homeomorphism.  And the undecidablility is again a fundamental group issue -- there's a certain type of group presentation called a Wirthinger presentation.  Given any such presentation there's an algorithm to construct a knot ($n>2$) such that $\pi_1$ of the complement has that Wirthinger presentation. 

Answer (score 36):

Is a given computable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable?

OK, I'll have to (1) clarify what I mean and (2) show it's not a completely trivial consequence of the halting problem.

Part (1):

I have to define computability of $f$. Say that a Turing machine computes a real $x$ if, given any input $n$, it always returns a sequence of $n$ rational numbers, with the $i$th element within $2^{-i}$ of $x$. In other words, it computes the initial part of a Cauchy sequence approximating $x$ to a predetermined accuracy.

Now we can say that a machine $X$ computes $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ if for any $x$, you can give it a description of a Turing machine to compute $x$ as an input, and always gives you back another one that computes $f(x)$.

It is impossible to make a machine that takes a description of a machine $X$ to compute $f$, and tells you if the function $f$ is differentiable, i.e. differentiability is undecidable.

But, you say, that's trivial. After all, the machine $X$ we're passing in as argument is, obviously, a machine, so we expect to meet the halting problem. So contrast with:

Part (2):
Integration over an interval *is* computable.

(I've probably made some typos in the above as it's not my field. So try [Computable Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=OPolVWVFDJYC&lpg=PR3&ots=_Ql_ffXjUC&dq=%22Computable%20Analysis%3A%20An%20Introduction%22&pg=PR3#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Klaus Weihrauch for more details.)

Comment: This is very similar to the fact that the pushforward of sheaves is easier to define, but the inverse image sheaf is significantly easier to computte.

Comment: Is there a direct analogy?  And is the inverse image easy to compute in some formal sense?  I also assume you're refering to $Rf_*$, not $f_*$.

Comment: This is an extremely nice example!  One question: as you point out, it’s not a *trivial* reduction to the halting problem.  But the proof is still, in the end, a (non-trivial) reduction to the halting problem, right?  This isn’t an example of an intermediate Turing degree, is it?

Comment: I would expect integration to be easier than differentiation, because every computable function is continuous and every continuous function is integrable (on a compact interval).  Thus to decide if a computable function is integrable is trivially computable: always return Yes.  To actually calculate the integral computably is harder but seems likely to work (and I happen to know that it does).

Comment: In contrast, not every continuous function is differentiable, so to decide if a computable function is differentiable (much less to decide if it's computably differentiable and if so to compute its derivative) might be impossible.  And so it is.

Comment: Peter -- It's true that this is not an example of an intermediate Turing degree, but it is also not a reduction to the halting problem, because the problem of verifying differentiability is much more difficult than the halting problem.  Because differentiability is naively a $\Pi^1_1$ property, the problem is reducible to Kleene's O.  This is optimal by a 1936 paper of Mazurkiewicz.  (His argument is reproduced in Kechris and Woodin's 1986 paper "Ranks of Differentiable Functions" as the original is hard to find.  The original argument was set-theoretic but it effectivizes.)

Answer (score 33):

Two open problems in this area that I like:

1. (related to the Tiling Problem mentioned by Hamkins) Is it undecidable whether a polyomino (as defined e.g. at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) tiles a rectangle? If $P$ is a polyomino that tiles a rectangle, let $f(P)$ be the least number of copies of $P$ that are needed to tile a rectangle, and let $p(n)$ be the maximum of $f(P)$ over all polynominoes with $n$ squares that tile a rectangle. If the answer to the question is positive (which is what people in the area believe and is sometimes erroneously claimed to be known), then $p(n)$ grows faster than any recursive function!
2. Let $F(x)=P(x)/Q(x)$ such that $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients and $Q(0)\neq 0$. Is it undecidable that the Taylor series expansion of $F(x)$ at $x=0$ has a zero coefficient?

Comment: It's staggering to learn that 2 does not have an easy decision procedure! I suppose that it has to do with diophantine properties of complex PF numbers (algebraic numbers with at least one conjugate with the same absolute value and none with larger).

Answer (score 29):

Team games, as defined in [Bob Hearn's thesis](http://erikdemaine.org/theses/bhearn.pdf) or the book *Games, Puzzles, and Computation*.   These are games, like bridge, in which there are two teams playing against each other and each team has several players who do not have complete information about the game.  The astounding thing is that even though there are only *finitely many game states*, it is undecidable to determine whether there is a winning strategy.  This seeming paradox arises because the players do not necessarily *know* that the game state has returned to a previous state, and a winning strategy can in principle depend on the entire history of the game.  I like this one because it takes some effort even to understand why it it not *trivially* decidable.

Comment: Nice. I like the 1-PFA problem for the same reason.

Comment: See also my note of June 3rd on this same problem.  It deserves double mention!

Answer (score 28):

The problem of distinguishing two manifolds (up to homeomorphism, or even homotopy equivalence **Edit:** given a triangulation) is undecidable.  This follows from the word problem applied to fundamental groups.

There are [similar problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems#Problems_in_topology) concerning simplicial complexes, e.g., whether a given complex is a triangulation of a manifold.

Comment: Distinguishing two manifolds given what information?  How do you "give" somebody two manifolds, and ask them if they are homotopy equivalent?  Do you mean if I give you an atlas for each manifold? Because I would still say this is a problem with distinguishing between representations.

Comment: There are many ways of making a precise statement. You could give a simplicial complex underlying a manifold. Or a handlebody decomposition (e.g. a Kirby diagram for a 4-manifold). Or even a finite list of polynomial equations with integer coefficients (whether this accounts for all manifolds doesn't really matter).

Comment: Sorry, I was being very sloppy.

Comment: An interesting special case is the problem of recognizing the $n$-sphere, proved unsolvable for $n\ge 5$ by S.P. Novikov in 1962. Incidentally, S.P. Novikov is the son of P.S. Novikov, who proved the unsolvability of the word problem for groups.

Comment: @John Stillwell: but I guess we can see from this example that the group on the generators ‘S’, ‘P’, and ‘Novikov’ does not prove that P.S = S.P!

Comment: @Peter: How does a group prove anything?

Answer (score 28):

Four from Compiler Science:

1. Does a program ever access an uninitialized variable.
2. Do two context free grammars describe the same language.
3. Does it make a difference if parameters to a subroutine are passed by reference or by copy-result
4. Deadlock determination in parallel programs.

Actually almost every question of the form "Does a program ever do X?" is equivalent to the halting problem.  So the above might be considered too close the the halting problem to be interesting answers ot this question.

Comment: I don't find it a flaw to be close to or equivalent to the halting problem. After all, in a robust sense I think all the answers posted here so far are equivalent to the Halting problem, in the sense of Turing equivalence. Undecidability in the cases of the answers is established ultimately by reducing the Halting problem to the given problem, and conversely, for each problem one can reduce it to the Halting problem. So all the posted problems have the same Turing degree as the Halting Problem.

Comment: Aren't these just special cases of Rice's Theorem?

Comment: @Christoph - no, Rice's theorem says we cannot decide nontrivial things about a the language of a program, but #1,3,4 do not deal with the program's language and #2 does not get programs as input.

Answer (score 25):

My favourite is related to the [Kolmogorov Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of a string:

> The problem of deciding if a string $s$ is compressible ($K(s) <^? |s| $) is undecidable

Answer (score 21):

Well if we're going to give easy ones, then: checking if two real numbers are equal.  As if you needed more reasons to be disturbed by the reals!

A special case of: checking if a vector $v$ in a finite dimensional vector space over the reals is linearly independent of a set of vectors $\{u_i\}$.

(almost equivalently: checking equality (in the sense of extensionality) of $k\geq 2$ bounded integer-valued functions.  the output of such functions can be written as real numbers in $[0,1]$, but you have to have to pad each integer so that you don't accidentally call two different outputs the same real number (due to $0.99\ldots = 1.00$ etc).  How to solve the halting problem: have a function $f(n) = 1$.  Given some arbitrary program/function, nest it in a function $g(n)$ which runs it for $n$ cycles, and outputs $1$ if it halted, $0$ otherwise.  $f$ and $g$ are equivalent iff the program does not halt.)

Comment: Although there is a sense in which this problem is not decidable, I think it is not a "problem" in the sense of the question, in the sense of Turing computability, since it is not finitely encodable. Namely, a *decidable* problem is a set of natural numbers whose characteristic function is computable by a Turing machine. An *undecidable* problem is a set of natural numbers not computable in this way. Many mathematical objects, such as finitely presented groups, finite graphs, etc. can be finitely described, allowing Turing machines to accept such a description as input.

Comment: @Joel This still applies for computable reals. Computable reals *are* finitely encodable.

Comment: Could someone add a reference for this, including Dan Piponis comment?

Comment: Michael, you are looking for the subject known as computable analysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis. It is an elementary argument via the recursion theorem to show that equality of computable reals is not computable; indeed, you cannot even decide if a computable number is zero. (If you have an algorithm that does decide this correctly, then design a program $p$ that pretends to be zero until your algorithm says it is zero, and then after this $p$ should make the real non-zero, a contradiction.) 

Comment: As Dan says, it applies to computable reals.  And if you can't decide whether two computable reals are equal, then certainly you can't decide whether two arbitrary reals are equal!  (This only to make the reals ‘disturbing’.)

Answer (score 19):

The following undecidable problem is natural for engineers in the sense that runtime estimation is an ubiquitous engineering problem associated to (for example) control theory and circuit design.

> **Viola's theorem**  Given an integer $k$ and Turing machine $M$ promised to be in P, the question "Is the runtime of $M$ of ${O}(n^k)$ with respect to input length $n$ ?" is undecidable.

The proof of this problem's undecidability was given on TCS StackExchange by Emanuele Viola in answer to the question [*Are runtime bounds in P decidable?*](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no)

**Background**

This question arose in parsing Luca Tevisan's answer on TCS StackExchange to the question [*Do runtimes for P require EXP resources to upper-bound? … are concrete examples known?*](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/do-runtimes-for-p-require-exp-resources-to-upper-bound-are-concrete-examples-k/4716#4716) (answer: yes and yes).

The illumination sought in asking/answering this question was a better appreciation/intuition regarding the practical aspects of runtime estimation in the complexity class P, in the sense of runtime estimates that are feasible (that is, require computational resources in P), versus infeasible (that is, require computational resources in EXP), versus formally undecidable (the instance above).

What this problem's undecidability shows us, perhaps, is that some aspects of P are richer and more subtle than is readily appreciated upon first acquaintance.

Answer (score 16):

This I think is interesting:  On a **finite** game board, but with an unbounded number of moves,
games pitting teams against one another, in the presence of imperfect information,
are undecidable.  "Imperfect information" is like that in Bridge (although Bridge has a bounded number of moves).  This result is proved in
*Games, Puzzles, & Computation*
by Robert Hearn and Erik Demaine, 2009.

Answer (score 16):

A variant of the "given a finite simplicial complex, is it the 5-sphere?" problem is the "given a finite simplicial complex, is it it a 6-manifold?".

I find this attractive because, because manifolds are such a basic and fundamental concept, you'd expect we'd be able to recognize one, but in fact we cannot.

This was pointed out by an answer to the question: [When are (finite) simplicial complexes (smooth) manifolds?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71400/when-are-finite-simplicial-complexes-smooth-manifolds)

Comment: In that case, how about "Given a 5-manifold (as a simplicial complex, say), is it the 5-sphere?"?

Answer (score 16):

My favorite example is the halting problem for Conway's "FRACTRAN" programming language: given a finite sequence of fractions q1, q2, ...., q_n, does the procedure "starting with a given integer and keep successively multiplying by the first element in the sequence which results in the product still being an integer until none of them do" halt? In fact there is specific sequence of fractions that is quite short which can be interpreted as a Universal machine.

Answer (score 15):

Above it was mentioned that, from a general finite group presentation, it is not decidable whether the group is finite. There are actually a bunch of group properties that are similarly undecidable - is it abelian, solvable, simple? But my favourite would be: does it have more than one element!?

Comment: The same for all Markov properties:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adian–Rabin_theorem

Answer (score 14):

The recognition problem for compact, simply connected contact manifolds of given dimension $2n-1\geq 11$ ([Seidel, 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2055)).

A contact structure on a $(2n-1)$-manifold is a tangent hyperplane field $\xi$ which can locally be written as $\ker\alpha$ for a 1-form $\alpha$ with $\alpha \wedge (d\alpha)^{n-1}$ non-vanishing. In principle there are finite ways to specify contact manifolds, using symplectic handlebody theory. But there's a simply connected contact manifold $(M_0,\xi_0)$ with the property that, given another, say $(M,\xi)$, the problem of deciding whether it's isomorphic to $(M_0,\xi_0)$ contains an algorithmically-unsolvable word problem for groups.

If you forget the contact structure, algorithmic recognition *is* possible (Nabutovsky-Weinberger).

Answer (score 13):

Suppose we specify a group $G$ by a set of relations, e.g. $x_1x_2x_3^{-1} = 1$.  Then, the problem of determining if $G$ is finite or not is undecidable.

Comment: Thanks for this example. To supplement your description, the undecidable problem is: given a finite group presentation, determine if the group it presents is finite or infinite. 

Answer (score 13):

For your "challenge" question, note that it is extremely hard to construct examples of problems of degree strictly less than the halting problem. In fact this was a question open for some years under the name of [Post's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post's_problem). It was finally solved by the invention of the "finite injury method" which gave many examples of such problems. However I do not know of any naturally formulated problem with degree strictly less than the halting problem.

Comment: To clarify, Friedberg and Muchnik's introduction of the "finite injury method" solved Post's Problem of the existence of intermediate **computably enumerable** degrees.  The existence of (non-computably enumerable) intermediate degrees was known before Friedberg and Muchnik via the "finite extension method" of Kleene and Post.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This was precisely the point of my challenge, to find out if there are any natural examples of such intermediate degrees, particularly c.e. such degrees. All known such degrees are the result of these kind of complicated constructions aimed specifically at producing such intermediate degrees. But it could be that there are natural sets of natural numbers that happen to have intermediate degree. (For example, how about the set of differences of primes $p-q$?) It is,  I believe, a major open question to find such natural instances of intermediate Turing degrees.

Answer (score 10):

From what I've been told, it is impossible to decide whether (in general) a complex holomorphic function has a zero at the origin.  Similarly, it is undecidable whether certain holomorphic functions have double zeros or zeros just "really" close to each other.  [It would really be interesting if this had some effect on things like the Riemann hypothesis or BSD.]

Comment: Statements like this do have an effect on the decidability of the Risch algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: What data is given on the function?

Comment: If you're given the Taylor expansion at the origin I'd hope it's decidable. :)

Comment: Re: Ryan -- As one can express real numbers such that there is no algorithm to determine if they are equal to zero, the answer is still no. [So, in some ways that makes my answer trivial, since then *polynomials* work.  But see the other comment below.]

Re: Mariano -- That's the big question!  How much information can we give and still be unable to determine whether such a function has a zero?  For a concrete example: Given the L-function associated to a rational elliptic curve of rank 4, can we algorithmically prove the analytic rank is 4?  From what I understand this is still open!

Comment: In Risch algorithm here is heuristic procedure needed in order to check if some algebraic form is equal to zero. This is because of The Theorem of Richardson which states what algebraic formulas are undecidable, see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RichardsonsTheorem.html.

Answer (score 10):

The [rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is also a cute one.

Comment: As well as for its own sake, I find this one intensely interesting from the non-mathematical standpoint: it's simple enough that it is quite plausible that lone molecules / simple groups of such could be working as universal Turing machines. Even more plausible when you consider that there are many such rules that are Turing complete. Mind boggling implications for biology.

Comment: "Rule 110" is not an "undecidable problem", and the Wikipedia page does not clearly state what is an undecidable problem related to it.

Comment: @VilleSalo It is of course decidable what the state will be after n steps. The Wikipedia tells that it is 'Turing Complete'. This implies that it is undecidable whether a cell will flip eventually to 1 given a certain begin state (so, not knowing the number of steps).

Comment: And how do you restrict the initial state? If you just have arbitrary computable sequences, then this problem is undecidable for the shift map. Is 110 more Turing complete than a shift map? Just to clarify, I know at least one useful answer to this question, and am just pointing out that this answer is not very good as it stands. (And yes technically I could fix it, but this would take much longer than complaining.)

Comment: (The downvote is not mine, and I'd love to see a precise version of this answer here.)

Comment: @VilleSalo I don't see the problem. If you have any Turing Complete system, then you can make an undecidable problem out of it. For the initial state, I assume (but I didn't researched it), that it is finite. So, that at a certain point to the left and right you only have zeros.

Comment: Why shouldn't one answer a precise mathematical question with an imprecise answer on MathOverflow? Do I really need to answer that? I will give three answers: 1) The danger with having to guess what Turing complete means in each specific case is that you can guess wrong. In this case, it is not hard to guess what the right answer is, but it's not trivial either. Your guess is wrong, or at least I have never seen this stated. It might be provable, or could just be false; certainly for some CA, the prediction problem is decidable on finite configurations, but not on eventually periodic ones.

Comment: 2) You say that if something has been shown to be "Turing complete", then some problem is undecidable. Probably. But I cannot help but be reminded of Wolfram's "(2,3) Turing machine". Alex Smith showed it's Turing complete. I read the proof (to a degree), and was convinced. Now, over a decade later, no one knows a good undecidable problem about it. Alex was a brilliant guy (and probably still is) and spent some effort trying to formalize the initial conditions, but it's not easy. Very weak CA/TM can lead to undecidable problems when your initial conditions are not eventually periodic.

Comment: 3) I would say your answer is like answering this with "The integers are a fun example!" Or it seems your answer is actually worse because if you search "integers undecidable problem", you will find an explicit statement on the first page (I tried it), while if you search "rule 110 undecidable problem", you will have to guess the right link to click on and browse for some time. Cook's papers have no theorems, so those are not the right guess unless you want to actually read the entire proof.

Comment: I'll add an explicit statement here, the following was stated in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.1039.pdf (my own recollection of what Cook proved is slightly different, but it's a long time since I read it). Given four finite words $u, v, w, t \in \{0,1\}^*$, it is undecidable whether there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sigma^m(f^n(...uuuwvvv...)) \in [t]$ where $f$ is rule 110, and $[t]$ denotes a cylinder.

Comment: @VilleSalo 1) I think your comments are valuable for people that want to know more about this. 2). The original question did not ask about proofs, but about 'attractive'. I think Rule 110 because of its simplicity. 3) If something is Turin complete, then it means that you can simulate a Turing machine in it and that means you can encode a Turing Halting problem in it. 4) However, there I agree with you, then you have to translate the problem back to the orginal construction. I didn't do that properly.

Comment: 5) You wrote "Now, over a decade later, no one knows a good undecidable problem about it." Undecidability is about a class of problems, not a single problem.

Comment: 5) Yes, and here by "problem" i mean a language (of encodings of instances to a problem).

Comment: 6) About "The integers are a fun example!". That is not a clear description of a system, while Rule 110 is. Are you referring to First Order Logic with Peano Axioms, that Godel used for his incompleteness theorem? Which actually proofs Turing Completeness, while that term was not invented yet?

Comment: 6) No, I'm referring to the ring of integers. It's a mathematical object. You can ask many problems about it, some are decidable, some are not. Same as with 110.

Comment: Anyway, I disagree with my old self. Actually, just saying "rule 110" is much less ambiguous than just saying "integers", since there is so little literature on rule 110 (that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 8):

A MODULAR SYSTEM $M$ is a finite set of "rules" of the form $ax+b\to cx+d$, 
with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$, then  $u$ is "derivable" from $v$ in $M$ if  one can get from $u$ to $v$ by applying  rules in $M$. For example, the well-known Collatz problem asks whether for all positive integers $u$, 1 is derivable from $u$ in the modular system with the two rules $2x\to x, 2x+1\to 6x+4$.

The general problem of whether $u$ is derivable from $v$ in a given modular system $M$ is undecidable. (Proved in Borger, "Computability, Complexity and Logic").

Answer (score 8):

Rice's Theorem is interesting. It states that only trivial properties of programs are decidable.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RicesTheorem.html

Answer (score 7):

In relation to the undecidability for 3x3 matrices and the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15766/) of 
https://mathoverflow.net/users/1587/john-stillwell that

"The corresponding problem for 2×2 matrices is apparently still open":

There is a recent proof that the membership for non-singular 2×2 integer matrices is decidable (i.e. for 2x2 integer matrices with nonzero determinant). http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02303

However in terms of uncedaibiltity the identity problem for 3x3 integer matrices is still open, while the general open problem about the identity matrix was proved to be undecidable for 4x4 matrices over integers , see

Paul C. Bell, Igor Potapov: On the Undecidability of the Identity Correspondence Problem and its Applications for Word and Matrix Semigroups. Int. J. Found. Comput. Sci. 21(6): 963-978 (2010) 
and arxiv.org/abs/0902.1975

solving the long standing open problem see Problem 10.3 in http://press.princeton.edu/math/blondel/solutions.html
Unsolved Problems in Mathematical Systems and Control. Theory, Princeton Univ. Press, 2004.

It also follows that whether a matrix semigroup is a group is undecidable for 4x4 integer matrices.

--- extra comments ------

Finally here are the comments about the importance of the are on matrix products.

Matrices and matrix products play a crucial role in the representation and analysis of various computational processes, i.e., linear recurrent sequences, arithmetic circuits, hybrid and dynamical systems, probabilistic and quantum automat, stochastic games, broadcast protocols, optical systems, etc. Many simply formulated and elementary problems for matrices are inherently difficult to solve even in dimension two, and most of these problems become undecidable in general starting from dimension three or four. One such hard question is the Membership Problem.

Even algorithmic problems for matrices over SL(2,Z) have many important complexity questions. They are appear in the context of many fundamental
problems from hyperbolic geometry, dynamical systems, Lorenz/modular knots, braid groups, particle physics, high energy physics, M/string theories, ray tracing analysis, music theory, etc.

I would like to also to cite Prof. J. N. Tsitsiklis http://www.mit.edu/~jnt/complex.html  from the webpage "Computational complexity in systems and control" which contains results on computational problems for matrix products:

"The subject is multifaceted and interesting in many different ways. It can help the practitioner in choosing problem formulations, and in calibrating expectations of what can be algorithmically accomplished. For the systems theorist or the applied mathematician, it raises a variety of challenging open problems that require a diverse set of tools from both discrete and continuous mathematics. Finally, for the theoretical computer scientist, the problems in systems and control theory provide the opportunity to relate abstractly defined complexity classes and specific problems of practical interest."

Comment: The audience will appreciate more if you can comment on the meaning of the decidability/undecidability of matrices, and why they are important and deep to choose as the most attractive Turing undecidable problems.

Comment: I added some comments to the post about the importance of the complexity/decidability status for matrix problems.

Answer (score 6):

Let a finite structure be a finite underlying set A 
along with a finite set of finitary operation from A to 
itself.  Such creatures are called algebras in the 
study of universal algebra, and one subarea of study is 
the equational theory of such a creature, i.e. the set 
of universally quantified equations which hold in the 
strucure (e.g. the associative law for semigroups).
The equational theory is said to be finitely based if 
there is a finite set of equations from which one can 
deduce precisely those equations in the equational 
theory.

A problem raised by Tarski and shown undecidable by 
McKenzie is Tarski's Finite Basis Problem: Given a 
finite structure , determine whether its equational 
theory is finitely based.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.01.12

Answer (score 6):

For completeness: Non trivial properties of languages are undecidable.

Comment: Yes, they are undecidable from the programs that decide them. See Rice's Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem

Comment: Yes, this *is* Rice's theorem. I am stating it for completeness of the list: I don't see it listed.

Answer (score 5):

Not mentioned yet, that any computer language extended with non-deterministic features is also Turing computable.

This is interesting, because it allows the language to be simplified. If the programs operate on objects that are *nil* or a pair. Then you only need five instructions:

- The constant *nil*
- A pair operator
- A sequence operator, that executes one code fragment after another
- An inverse operator
- A closure operator, which repeats a code fragment zero or multiple times

If you want to construct a piece code of that adds the two values of a pair, then first make something that construct (a - 1, b + 1) from (a, b). Then take the closure. This will generate (a - n, b + n). Finally, pick the value (0, c) and output c. This can be done by using the inverse operator on the pair and nil.

So, programming is a little bit odd, because you select the right value outside the loop (closure), rather than inside the loop, as in deterministic languages. The advantages is the much more simpler structure. No variables, no recursion, no matching operators (just use the inverse) and no control-structures, except closure.

This makes it a little bit between programming and mathematics. The simpler structure, allows easier mathematical reasoning. So, it might be an idea to convert a program in a deterministic language, to a program of a simplified non-deterministic language, before doing any mathematics on the program.

Lucas

Answer (score 5):

In your last criterion, you are essentially asking for a "natural" problem that is nonrecursive, recursively enumerable, and is not complete for the recursively enumerable sets.  Post proved the existence of such problems in *[Recursively enumerable sets of positive integers and their decision problems](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1944-50-05/S0002-9904-1944-08111-1/)*, for many-one reductions.  Friedberg and Muchnik proved this also holds for Turing reductions, in separate papers *[Two recursively enumerable sets of incomparable degrees of unsolvability (solution of Post's problem, 1944)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/89817)* and *On the unsolvability of the problem of reducibility in the theory of algorithms*.  Whether these are "attractive" is probably determined by whether you like nonconstructive arguments.  For a clear and self-contained exposition of these results, see Kozen's book Theory of Computation.

So this is only a partial answer, and it would still be nice to exhibit a *real* problem with intermediate degree.

Edit: in the survey *[Degrees of Unsolvability](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~fejer/articles/History_of_Degrees.pdf)* (which appears to be a chapter of an unpublished Volume 9 of the [Handbook of the History of Logic](http://www.johnwoods.ca/HHL/)), Ambos-Spies and Fejer state "it is fair to say that every particular c.e. set of natural numbers that has arisen from nonlogical considerations so far is either computable or complete... Thus one could say that the great complexity in the structure of the c.e. degrees arises solely from studying unnatural problems."  This is quite a negative assessment!  On a more positive note, Feferman showed in *[Degrees of Unsolvability Associated with Classes of Formalized Theories](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964178)* that every c.e. degree arises as the degree of some recursively axiomatizable consistent theory of first-order predicate calculus.

Comment: Yes, to find what you call a *real* problem was my point. One can build intermediate degrees via priority argument constructions, and I like those argumens very much (and I do find them constructive), but to my knowledge there is no such intermediate degree arising outside such constructions. I would also recommend Soare's book on the Computably Enumerable Sets and Degrees.

Comment: I don't know if this counts, but "exotic" c.e. sets do arise in the results of Nabutovsky and Weinberger on Riemannian geometry.  See Soare's exposition "Computability theory and differential geometry."

Comment: Thx for adding that info but a small correction.  The Friedburg-Muchnick result is kinda what is meant by non-natural.  A natural problem would be one which, at a minimum, is defined in some way other than via a priority argument.  Credit for solving that question generally goes to Harrington (might be forgetting a coauthor but only Harrington was my grad advisor so hopefully they'll understand) who discovered a certain property expressed in terms of the structure of r.e. sets which is only satisfied by incomplete sets.

Answer (score 4):

My own favorite is that effective first-order theories are in general semi-decidable (ie, recursively enumerable), which follows from the conjunction of Godel's completeness and incompleteness theorems.

Answer (score 4):

As a computer scientist, it would be nice to know if a program contains [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) or [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Answer (score 4):

Type inference for sufficiently powerful type systems, e.g. System F

Answer (score 4):

In control theory, simultaneous stabilization of 3 or more systems is undecidable (necessary and sufficient conditions for simultaneous stabilization of 2 systems are known). This and other stabilization problems are discussed in Blondel and Tsitsiklis, A survey of computational complexity results in systems and control, Automatica, 2000, vol36 n9 p1249--1274, and its references.

Answer (score 4):

Given a finite relational language with at least one binary relation, the question of which formulas are finitely satisfiable (i.e. realized in at least one finite structure) is $\Sigma^0_1$ but not computably enumerable (by [Trakhtenbrot's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trakhtenbrot's_theorem))

Comment: It's the other way around: Finite satisfiability is computably enumerable (by searching systematically through all finite structures) but not decidable and thus not `$\Pi^0_1$`.  (It's the reverse of what happens for satisfiability in arbitrary (not necessarily finite) structures.)  (This is word-for-word my earlier comment, now deleted, except for fixing a couple of typos, one of which was omission of "not" before "decidable".)

Comment: Woops. I fixed it. I had initially thought to write "finitely valid" but decided to say "satisfisfiable" instead and forgot to change the $\Pi$ to $\Sigma$. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice one: V. D. Blondel, O. Bournez, P. Koiran, C. Papadimitriou, J. N. Tsitsiklis, Deciding stability and mortality of piecewise affine dynamical systems, Theoretical Computer Science, 255: (1-2), pp. 687-696, 2001. (http://www.inma.ucl.ac.be/~blondel/publications/99BBKPT-plstab.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The emptiness problem for 1-way probabilistic finite state automata is undecidable. (See Condon Lipton Frievalds (sp?).)

Answer (score 3):

Say that an algorithm is *reliable* if given a string $S$ and integer $N$, it either halts and prints $|S|>N$ (meaning that Kolmogorov complexity of the string $S$ is greater than $N$) or does not halt, and never gives a false answer. For example, an algorithm that never halts on any input is reliable.

For any reliable algorithm $A$ there exists an integer $K$ such that for all $N>K$, $A(S,N)$ does not halt on any string (but note that for all strings except a finite set, $|S|>N$ actually holds).

Comment: nice, but does it answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Note that any set of intermediate Turing degree must lie in $L$; so I nominate the least such, with respect to the canonical ordering of $L$.

I suppose this set might have already been mentioned--it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of Matiyasevich's theorem, there is a constant $c$, and a Diophantine equation on $n+1$ parameters and $m$ variables:

$$D(K,a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)=0$$

including a parameter $K$ such that, for each $K\ge c$, there is no algorithm to determine whether the Diophantine equation has an infinite number of solutions or a finite number of solutions.

A similar result holds by replacing "infinite" with "even" and "finite" with "odd."

Here, the Diophantine equation has an infinite (resp. even) number of solutions iff the $K$'th bit of $\Omega$ is $1$ (where $\Omega$ is Chaitin's Constant.)

See, e.g., Ord and Kieu, "On the existence of a new family of equations for $\Omega$" ([link](http://amirrorclear.net/files/on-the-existence-of-a-new-family-of-diophantine-equations-for-omega.pdf))