# Turing degrees of nonstandard models of PA

Tags: computability-theory, peano-arithmetic, lo.logic

Since the theorems of (PA + "there is a nonstandard number") are recursively enumerable, by the

[Low Basis Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_basis_theorem), [WKL0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#Weak_K.C3.B6nig.27s_lemma_WKL0)'s proof of the completeness theorem gives a nonstandard model of PA of [low degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_(computability).  After seeing Adam Day's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29550/completeness-easiest-hardest-problems/35566#35566) to

[this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29550/completeness-easiest-hardest-problems), I wonder "how easy" such a model could be to compute.

Can a low nonstandard model of PA be:

a) minimal

b) computably dominated

c) K-trivial

?

If it can be more than one of those, which can it be simultaneously?

Comment: If anyone knows how to link directly to Adam Day's answer, please edit the question to do so.

Comment: Focusing on part (a): Jockusch and Soare (1972) showed that the PA degrees are precisely the degrees of $DNR_2$ functions (i.e., diagonally nonrecursive functions with range $\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace$), and Simpson (1977) proved that the PA degrees are those degrees which compute a path through every infinite tree. I believe that either of these results should suffice to show that there can be no nonstandard model of PA with minimal degree, let alone a low such model; but I am uncertain of this.

Comment: Although, the more I think about it, I don't see a way to actually show this; so maybe I'm just wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

b) is impossible, because the only low computably dominated degree is $\mathbf 0$ (see Soare's book *Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees*) and there are no computable nonstandard models of PA.

a) (minimal) and c) (K-trivial) are also impossible. See Theorem 4.2 of Csima/Harizanov/Hirschfeldt/Shore, *Bounding homogeneous models*. They give literature references for the fact that computing the atomic diagram of a nonstandard model of PA is equivalent to computing a PA degree, i.e., a complete extension of PA. Such a Turing degree cannot be minimal, because a PA degree bounds a 1-random degree, and the even and odd halves of a 1-random set are of incomparable degree. A PA degree cannot be K-trivial because each K-trivial degree is c.e. traceable, which implies it is not a DNR degree, which implies it is not a PA degree. See Nies, *Computability and Randomness*, Oxford Logic Guides, 2009.